# How to update version of JAXB RI used in JDK?

Tags: java, java-8, jaxb, java-7, jaxb2

When I compile my XSD with JDK 8 I get the output I expect.

When I compile my XSD with JDK 7 it appears to not read my binding.xjb file.

I'm pretty sure it's down to one of the many defects fixed between jaxb-v2

- JDK7 first release     JAXB RI 2.2.4-1
- JDK8 first release     JAXB RI 2.2.8

Release notes: [JAXB](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/release-documentation.html#a-2-2-7)

Can someone help me work out how to, if possible, update the version of JAXB RI that is used by the JDK?

I am building with Maven and am using the dependencies of...

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>0.6.4</version>
  </dependency>
```

The plugin I am using is...

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <catalog>target/classes/catalog.cat</catalog>
          <strict>false</strict>
          <extension>true</extension>
          <schemaIncludes>
            <include>*.xsd</include>
          </schemaIncludes>
          <bindingIncludes>
            <include>*.xjb</include>
          </bindingIncludes>
          <generatePackage>com.pcmsgroup.v21.esi.deviceservice.bean</generatePackage>
          <args>
            <arg>-XtoString</arg>
            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
            <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
            <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
            <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
            <arg>-XenumValue</arg>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
          </args>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
              <version>0.9.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
              <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
              <version>0.6.5</version>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <catalog>target/classes/catalog.cat</catalog>
      <strict>false</strict>
      <extension>true</extension>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <include>*.xsd</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
      <bindingIncludes>
        <include>*.xjb</include>
      </bindingIncludes>
      <generatePackage>com.jeff.bean</generatePackage>
      <args>
        <arg>-XtoString</arg>
        <arg>-Xequals</arg>
        <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
        <arg>-Xinheritance</arg>
        <arg>-Xcopyable</arg>
        <arg>-XenumValue</arg>
        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
      </args>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
          <version>0.9.5</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
          <version>0.6.5</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

I could be approaching this wrong, and maybe I need to look at `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin`

---

This shows the difference between a JDK and JDK 8 runs.
On the left, it seems to ignore the binding.xjc file and so doesn't know the enums size.
[image: JDK 7 vs JDK 8]

We can also see that the java class generated has different types.
[image: Generated java file]

Also, it generates Adapter classes in JDK 8 but not in JDK 7.
[image: Generated files]

Comment: `0.6.4` is an extremely old version of JAXB2 Basics. Just saying.

Comment: Please commit a PR with a sample project here: https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin-support
Under j/jdk7.
There are differences between JAXB versions but [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin] normally uses a specific version bundled with it. Differences due to JDK versions are... surprizing, I'll be willing to look at it.
**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of `maven-jaxb2-plugin` and JAXB2 Basics.

Comment: By the way, are you sure this is not JDK 9 related? I had a problem with bindings not processed on JDK 9. This is fixed in `0.14.0` version of the [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin].

Answer (score 0):

Few suggestions:

1. **args** are defined at two places. One under `/plugin/executions/execution/configuration/args` and one under `/plugin/configuration/args`. You can have it just in `/plugin/configuration/args`.
2. Under /plugin/configuration, there are two attributes **schemaDirectory** and **bindingDirectory**. Not able to see that in above plugin usage, are both xsds and xjbs lying in resources directory itself?
3. Can you try setting up these parameters too:
   **forceRegenerate**=true and **cleanPackageDirectories**=false.

Just mentioning a sample plugin definition for reference, you can trim details you don't need.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.8.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <generatePackage>com.some.sample.package</generatePackage>
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <bindingDirectory>src/main/resources/xjb</bindingDirectory>
        <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</generateDirectory>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
            <arg>-no-header</arg>
            <arg>-Xxew</arg>
            <arg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</arg>
            <arg>-Xxew:delete</arg>
            <arg>-XtoString</arg>
            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
            <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
            <arg>-Xvalue-constructor</arg>
            <arg>-Xfluent-api</arg>
            <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb2.basics.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-fluent-api</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb2.fluentapi.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-value-constructor</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb2.value.constructor.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                <version>${jaxb2.basics.annotate.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>abc.xsd</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>abc.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <include>abc.binding.xml</include>
                </bindingIncludes>
                <generatePackage>com.some.sample.package.transfer</generatePackage>
                <removeOldOutput>false</removeOldOutput>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <cleanPackageDirectories>false</cleanPackageDirectories>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.xew.plugin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.xjc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.xjc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>


<jaxb2.basics.version>0.9.2</jaxb2.basics.version>
<jaxb.xew.plugin.version>1.1</jaxb.xew.plugin.version>
<jaxb.xjc.version>2.2.6</jaxb.xjc.version>
<jaxb2.fluentapi.version>3.0</jaxb2.fluentapi.version>
<jaxb2.value.constructor.version>3.0</jaxb2.value.constructor.version>
<javax.xml.bind.version>2.2.6</javax.xml.bind.version>
<jaxb2.basics.annotate.version>1.0.4</jaxb2.basics.annotate.version>
```

Comment: Thanks, but none of that helps with JAXB not finding the bindings file under JDK 7.

Comment: Can you share the minimal project  structure, maven logs and pom section to understand further.

Comment: `0.8.3` is a very old version of [tag:maven-jaxb2-plugin].